# regex search a string for contents between two strings

Tags: javascript, regex, expression

I am trying my upmost best to get my head around regex, however not having too much luck.

I am trying to search within a string for text, I know how the string starts, and i know how the string ends, I want to return ALL the text inbetween the string including the start and end.

Start search = **[{"lx":**

End search = **}]**

i.e

[{"lx":**variablehere**}]

So far I have tried

```
/^\[\{"lx":(*?)\}\]/;
```

and

```
/(\[\{"lx":)(*)(\}\])/;
```

But to no real avail... can anyone assist?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably making the mistake of believing the `*` is a wildcard. Use the period (`.`) instead and you'll be fine.

Also, are you sure you want to stipulate zero or more? If there *must* be a value, use + (one or more).

**Javascript:**

```
'[{"lx":variablehere}]'.match(/^\[\{"lx":(.+?)\}\]/);
```

Comment: You might want to make `+` non-greedy like ioseb did

Answer (score 1):

The `*` star character multiplies the preceding character. In your case there's no such character. You should either put `.`, which means "any character", or something more specific like `\S`, which means "any non whitespace character".

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution:

```
var s = '[{"lx":variablehere}]';
var r = /\[\{"(.*?)":(.*?)\}\]/;
var m = s.match(r);

console.log(m);
```

Results to this array:

```
[ '[{"lx":variablehere}]',
  'lx',
  'variablehere',
  index: 0,
  input: '[{"lx":variablehere}]' ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\[\{"lx"\:(.*)\}\]
```

This should work for you. You can reach the captured variable by \1 notation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    ^\[\{\"lx\"\:(.*)\}\]$
```

all text between [{"lx": and }] you will find in backreference variable (something like \$1 , depends on programming language).